# how to fixed a navbar and Carousel image slider in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a header with a navbar and a Carousel sliding image using bootstrap 
how can i fixed this two together on scroll 
when the user scroll the website to see the information the navbar and carousel still fixed on the top and the information scroll under the header

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="factory.html">Factory</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="client.html">Clients</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="video.html">Video</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
     <img src="img/logo%20corner.png" class="center-block img-responsive imglogo">
    </div>
    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide1.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide2.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide3.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i have understood I give you a link where you can find your happiness.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Hope help you :)

Comment: thanks but i want the header and the navbar be fixed not the background

Answer (score 0):

I added the full code for you to have as a resource to reference with your document because what you posted is the stock bootstrap template with no input. Double check and make sure you have the latest bootstrap installed and are linking the files correctly. Below I used a CDN, but its better to have it downloaded.

The main thing to make sure you have the fixed header navigation is the following code:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

You can find the above code in the below code. Let me know if you have any questions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Whatever</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://www.bootply.com" target="ext">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</div>
<!-- /navbar wrapper -->


<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/root/directory/file_path.jpg" class="fill">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
            <pthis is="" an="" example="" layout="" with="" carousel="" that="" uses="" the="" bootstrap="" 3="" styles.<="" small="">
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
              </p>
            </pthis>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/root/directory/file_path.jpg" class="fill">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
            <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me the navbar is fixed bs the image of Carousel is not